# Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact

Tags: maven, jersey, pom.xml

This my pom.xml and the errors I get are:

> Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:pom:2.9 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org @ line 14, column 25: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

and

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:jar is missing. @ line 25, column 21

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple-service</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.9</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

I have tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500332/non-resolvable-parent-pom-could-not-transfer-artifact-when-trying-to-refer-to) but there wasn't any change. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: this is the problem: `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org` check your network connection etc.

Comment: Thanks, the network seems to be working fine.

Comment: But does the second error also network related?

Comment: If you have a Unknown host the network does **NOT** work. Or you have no internet access and might need to configure proxy etc. Apart from that after fixing networks things remove your complete local repository and start from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown host error while executing MVN install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615140/unknown-host-error-while-executing-mvn-install)

Answer (score 14):

Fixed the issue by modifying the settings.xml to reflect the firewall properties within my organisation. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem. Where is this settings.xml file located?

Comment: maven-installation-location/conf/settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had same issue. It was because in settings.xml password was incorrect. After reset my correct password it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may also be due to the fact that the version for both Maven and the JDK is not configured correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).