# Non-resolvable import POM error on Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, lagom

I have a Maven project on IntelliJ IDE (Linux machine).
I want to build the project using the command line, but there is an error:

Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-maven-dependencies:pom....

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083936/non-resolvable-import-pom-could-not-transfer-artifact)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: maven is not finding on repository the artifact of this groupid com.lightbend.lagom. It can be different situations... Are you on behind a proxy on the network? Is there some mirror on your settings.xml? Is there another repository on your pom? Please post your entire pom.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related with the network.

You may need to modify maven *settings.xml* to reflect the firewall properties within your organisation.